# <input> in <div> takes up extra space on right

Tags: css

I have an input element inside a div element:

```
...
<div id="calculator-container">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
....
```

In CSS I make the input width 100%:

```
#calculator-container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#calculator-container input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I can't figure out why is there less free space on the right side of the input than on the left (please see the screenshot below).  Maybe somebody can advise.  Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

---

**Pointing out that on jsfiddle it looks fine but if you copy it locally it looks bad in both IE and Firefox.  Here is the jsfiddle link just so you can copy the code: [jsfiddle just to get the code](http://jsfiddle.net/sbel/v9fqZ/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s because `width` means the width of the element’s *content area*. The `<input>`’s content area is surrounded by its padding and border.

- http://jsfiddle.net/3f7RB/

If you set those to `0`, the input no longer takes up more space than is available:

```
input {
    width: 100%;
    border-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/3f7RB/1/

(Of course, form elements are often rendered a bit differently from regular elements, so different browsers may do different things.)

If you want padding on the `<input>`, you can either declare that as a percentage too:

```
input {
    width: 96%;
    border-style: none;
    padding: 4px 2%;
}
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/3f7RB/5/

Or use `box-sizing` (not supported in IE 6 or 7) so that `width: 100%` applies to the `<input>`’s content, padding and border combined:

```
input {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/3f7RB/6/

Answer (score 1):

Because the input element gets `width:100%` which is 200px. this however doesnt take into account that it has a border of 2px, meaning it actually should be 196px. 
try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/QLFrj/

```
#calculator-container input {
    width: 196px;
}
```

Only problem is that it is no longer a percentage...

Answer (score 1):

the reason why it's to right because of the `border` because it's to the `width` of `input field` means the `width of input field is 100% + 2px`. So, you can use `box-sizing` property got this:

Check this

### http://jsfiddle.net/3f7RB/4/

**OR**

you can use `outline` property also . like this:

Check this

### http://jsfiddle.net/3f7RB/7/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried here and it works fine. Maybe another CSS statement is overriding some attributes of your div or input. You may try to inspect the elements with Firebug (on Firefox) or Google Chrome.

[image: Take a look]

Comment: Provide the code and screenshots please. IMHO, this can't be true. **edit:** I'm sorry, only FF applies this. Every other browser fails.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using Firefox.

Comment: @Sn0opy I've validated the CSS and HTML.  I've checked on both Firefox and IE.  I've put the code to [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sbel/v9fqZ/).  I see that on jsfiddle it looks fine but if you copy locally it doesn't look right.

Comment: The output in jsfiddle is unreliable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your input element wants to be 200px too. The `width: 100%` applies to the parent-element. In this case the `#calculator-container`.

Comment: `#calculator-container input` rule does certainly not apply to the input's parent container.

Comment: @Juhana: correct. I think @Sn0opy means that the `width: 100%` rule means that the input’s width will be 100% of the parent element’s width.